# How to use opacity on content and content::before without overlapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 as my grid framework along with css to create a semi-transparent area with one skewed/slanted edge, but am running into problems with my elements due to layered opacity.

The expectation is that the center is slanted, but the right side is still square.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? 
Please see the jsfiddle for a working example.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row marketing-text">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <!-- Intentionally empty, jsfiddle was giving me issues with the offset -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 right">
            <h5 class="uppercase">Header Text</h5>
            <p>Long Text Input</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
.row.marketing-text .right {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 139, 0, 0.5);
}
.row.marketing-text .right::before {
    content: " ";
    transform-origin: top;
    -ms-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
    transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 139, 0, 0.5);
}
</style>
```

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/255707/

Comment: What problem are you having?  You said something about layered opacity?

Comment: The problem is that the layered pieces cause differences in the intended transparency

Answer (score 1):

Referring your example, Overlapping layers having `background-color` with opacity/rgba value will definitely not achieve the desired output.

Better way to accomplish this would be using `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements

[image]